# Fuel consumption problem

Tags: toyota, fuel-consumption, corolla

Morning I have a Toyota Corolla LE 2004 model, it consumption level is very high as in 50lt can finish in 2 day from my office to back home with is a 15 minute drive. I have scanned the vehicle several time got the exhaust changed, fuel pump, power plugs, so far nothing works still consumption is extremely very high.

Comment: Welcome to the site. How many miles (kms) are there on the vehicle? Have have you replaced the O2 (lambda) sensors? What is the fuel consumption you'd expect (how many l/km)? What *exact* fuel consumption are you experiencing (how many l/km)?

Comment: 15 min drive is first and second or cruising in 5th?? Completely different for consumption...

Comment: Fuel leak.  Or someone stealing fuel.

Comment: @harper +1 for stealing fuel - seen it happen !!